# How can I wipe RAM after shutdown

Tags: shutdown, ram

I  have  heard  about memtest86  how  can  I  install  it  to  Debian ? Is  it  good ?

https://gitlab.tails.boum.org/tails/blueprints/-/wikis/more_efficient_memory_wipe/memtest86plus/

Or do  I  use  what  offered  by  openAI?

nano /etc/rc.local

````
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger```

Could  you  suggest  a  good  method  for  wipe  RAM  and  how  to  install  it
````

Comment: What does this have to do with "wiping"? What does openAI have to do with any of this? What does sysrq have to do with memtest86+?

Answer (score 0):

[Memtest86+](https://memtest.org/) is indeed [available in Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/memtest86+), and can be installed with

```
sudo apt install memtest86+
```

The version currently in Debian 11 only supports BIOS boot; you’ll find an entry in the GRUB menu.

The latest version available in the forthcoming Debian 12 supports UEFI boot too; it is also available in backports for Debian 11.

Memtest86+’s main purpose is to test memory, but as a side-effect it will thoroughly wipe the contents of your RAM.

Comment: Thank  you  but  could  you  not  know  a  faster  solution for  wiping ram  ?